# How to query with unknown combination of optional parameters in SQL Server without cursors?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a search that has three input fields (for arguments sake, let's say LastName, Last4Ssn, and DateOfBirth).  These three input fields are in a dynamic grid where the user can choose to search for one or more combinations of these three fields.  For example, a user might search based on the representation below:

```
LastName    Last4Ssn    DateOfBirth
--------    --------    -----------
Smith       NULL        1/1/1970
Smithers    1234        NULL
NULL        5678        2/2/1980
```

In the example, the first row represents a search by LastName and DateOfBirth.  The second, by LastName and Last4Ssn.  And, the third, by Last4Ssn and DateOfBirth.  This example is a bit contrived as the real-world scenario has four fields.  At least two of the fields must be filled (don't worry about how to validate) with search data and it is possible that *all* fields are filled out.

Without using cursors, how does one use that data to join to existing tables using the *given* values in each row as the filter?  Currently, I have a cursor that goes through each row of the above table, performs the join based on the columns that have values, and inserts the found data into a temp table.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #results (
    Id INT,
    LastName VARCHAR (26),
    Last4Ssn VARCHAR (4),
    DateOfBirth DATETIME
)

DECLARE @lastName VARCHAR (26)
DECLARE @last4Ssn VARCHAR (4)
DECLARE @dateOfBirth DATETIME

DECLARE search CURSOR FOR
    SELECT LastName, Last4Ssn, DateOfBirth
    FROM #searchData

OPEN search
    FETCH NEXT FROM search
    INTO @lastName, @last4Ssn, @dateOfBirth

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN           
        INSERT INTO #results
            SELECT s.Id, s.LastName, s.Last4Ssn, s.DateOfBirth
            FROM SomeTable s
            WHERE Last4Ssn = ISNULL(@last4Ssn, Last4Ssn)
                AND DateOfBirth = ISNULL(@dateOfBirth, DateOfBirth)
                AND (
                    LastName = ISNULL(@lastName, LastName)
                    OR LastName LIKE @lastName + '%'
                )
        FETCH NEXT FROM search
        INTO @lastName, @last4Ssn, @dateOfBirth
    END
CLOSE search
DEALLOCATE search
```

I was hoping there was some way to avoid the cursor to make the code a bit more readable.  Performance is not an issue as the table used to search will never have more than 5-10 records in it, but I would think that for more than a few, it'd be more efficient to query the data all at once rather than one row at a time.  The `SomeData` table in my example can be very large.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't just join the two tables together:

```
CREATE TABLE #results (
    Id INT,
    LastName VARCHAR (26),
    Last4Ssn VARCHAR (4),
    DateOfBirth DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #results
select s.id, s.lastname, s.last4ssn, s.dateofbirth
from SomeTable s
join #searchData d
    ON s.last4ssn = isnull(d.last4ssn, s.last4ssn)
    AND s.dateofbirth = isnull(d.dateofbirth, s.dateofbirth)
    AND (s.lastname = isnull(d.lastname, s.lastname) OR
        OR s.lastname like d.lastname + '%')
```

EDIT:

Since the data is large, we'll need some good indices. One index isn't good enough since you effectively have 3 clauses OR'd together. So the first step is to create those indices:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeData (
    Id INT identity(1,1),
    LastName VARCHAR (26),
    Last4Ssn VARCHAR (4),
    DateOfBirth DATETIME
)

create nonclustered index ssnlookup on somedata (last4ssn)
create nonclustered index lastnamelookup on somedata (lastname)
create nonclustered index doblookup on somedata (dateofbirth)
```

The next step involves crafting the query to use those indices. I'm not sure what the best way here is, but I think it's to have 4 queries union'd together:

```
with searchbyssn as (
  select somedata.* from somedata join #searchData 
    on somedata.last4ssn = #searchData.last4ssn
), searchbyexactlastname as (
  select somedata.* from somedata join #searchData
    on somedata.lastname = #searchData.lastname
), searchbystartlastname as (
  select somedata.* from somedata join #searchData
    on somedata.lastname like #searchdata.lastname + '%'
), searchbydob as (
  select somedata.* from somedata join #searchData 
    on somedata.dateofbirth = #searchData.dateofbirth
), s as (
  select * from searchbyssn
  union select * from searchbyexactlastname
  union select * from searchbystartlastname
  union select * from searchbydob
)
select s.id, s.lastname, s.last4ssn, s.dateofbirth
from s
join #searchData d
   ON (d.last4ssn is null or s.last4ssn = d.last4ssn)
   AND s.dateofbirth = isnull(d.dateofbirth, s.dateofbirth)
   AND (s.lastname = isnull(d.lastname, s.lastname)
       OR s.lastname like d.lastname + '%')
```

Here's a fiddle showing the 4 index seeks: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3741d/3

It shows significant resource usage for the union, but I think that would be negligible compared to the index scans for large tables. It wouldn't let me generate more than a few hundred rows of sample data. Since the number of result rows is small, it is not expensive to join to #searchData at the end and filter all the results again.

Comment: Exactly what I started doing before you answered.  With the `SomeData` table being large, it takes about 4 seconds to run and is currently doing an index scan as there's only one index it seems to use that covers the fields being joined to.

Comment: @sumo I've added a new query and 3 indices that work together to make the SomeData access exclusively index seeks.

Comment: The new query doesn't seem to solve the original requirements as the original query uses `AND` between the optional parameters.  Using union there, you effectively do an `OR` which will not produce the correct results.  The query must `AND` at least two of the supplied parameters, which is why it's been particularly difficult to optimize.

Comment: @Sumo Good point. I missed that you can supply more than one parameter in each row. I've updated the answer to join to #searchData again at the end.